# What are "regional bid and ask prices"?

Tags: united-states, stocks, bid-ask, market-data

I was reading Schwab's [market data catalog](http://content.schwab.com/web/scs/pdf/AS_MarketData_Pricing_Guide_v4.pdf). Excerpt:

> NYSE Pro
>
> New York Stock Exchange (NYSE) offers Level I quote data for all NYSE-listed stocks and ETFs, providing:
>
> • Trades
>
> • National Best Bid and Offer (NBBO)
>
> • Regional Bid and Ask prices (stocks only)

I know what NBBO is, but what are "regional bid and ask prices"?

Answer (score 1):

> [A regional stock exchange](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/regionalstockexchange.asp)  is a stock exchange not located in that country's primary financial center, and where regional companies are listed. Often, companies who cannot meet the strict listing requirements of a national exchange may qualify for a listing on a regional exchange, though a company that qualifies to be on a national exchange may also register for a listing on one or more regional exchanges.

[Some examples would be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_stock_exchange#:%7E:text=A%20regional%20stock%20exchange%20is%20a%20term%20used,the%20SEC%20%27s%20Unlisted%20Trading%20Privileges%20%28UTP%29%20rule.):

- Boston: Primary focus is  mutual funds.
- Chicago: Trades regionally listed stocks and stocks from other exchanges
- Pacific: Known for derivatives

Comment: The NYSE is not a regional exchange. Why would does it provide regional bid and ask prices? Is the NYSE merely reselling the data obtained from regional exchanges?

Comment: @Flux imagine the scenario of a company listed on the Nasdaq, but traded on the NYSE pursuant to unlisted trading privilege.  I think from the perspective of a market data provider, NYSE would be a regional in that scenario